# Should I go up to my reporting manager and ask my team?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, new-job

I have recently switched my job and joined a bigger and a better company.
A week has passed and I am not assigned any tasks yet. I have free time right now and don't know which team I will join.

Is it advisable that I approach my reporting manager and ask him about my expected team and when I would get my first task? Or is it OK to enjoy this period in a new place? What impression would this question leave on my reporting manager?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you have free time? There may be the expectation that in your new position there would be setting up your computer and other basic things that you'd do and then come ask for something to work. Alternatively, there may be systems that assign tasks that you aren't looking to see what is being given to you.

I'd talk to the manager about how to find what to work and what kinds of expectations are had as this seems like a very dangerous path to have for an extended period of time more than a day or two. I have had situations where in a new position that I didn't have anything to do for most of my first day while my computer was put together and initial software configured but to have an entire week with nothing being given I'd suspect there could be some miscommunication here.

Comment: Hmmm.. I think may be my manager has forgotten ;). I will definitely approach him today. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it advisable that I approach my reporting manager and ask him about
>   my expected team and when I would get my first task?

Yes!

If for some reason you have gone a week and haven't yet spoken to your manager, don't wait - do it now.

When you talk with her/him make sure you learn what the expectations are, and what you should be doing now.

> Or is it OK to enjoy this period in a new place? What impression would
>   this question leave on my reporting manager?

By "enjoy this period" I assume you mean just hanging around getting paid but doing nothing.
That's certainly not advisable. Managers appreciate people who are self-starters. They don't appreciation people who want to be told how they should spend every hour each day.

You risk looking like you will take advantage of any opening to just slack off. You don't want that to be your first impression.

Comment: Yes..I approached him and asked him about all the things. :)